# Grabbing / Printing Data from XML

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

Alright I have this down to the point where I can get the XML file generated. now I am trying to bring it back into the program to be used to store coordinates. Here is what I am working on in this specific part.

```
def diplayX():
root = etree.parse('c:\\Users\namehere\Desktop\coord_man.xml').getroot()
x = root.findtext(x1elm)
print(x)
```

Since the XML file being copy pasted would not show the code but just the numbers here is a copy of the XML in question. Changed the name on the web not that it makes a huge difference.
http://pastebin.com/yQfdFgwr

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
sloop()
File "C:\Users\namehere\Desktop\Folder of CodeMonkey\piSrc\pyclickerXML.py", line 71,    in sloop
x = root.findtext(x1elm)
NameError: global name 'x1elm' is not defined
```

x1elm = 300 in the named XML file. Which was generated by a previous method in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The searchtext `x1elm` needs to be within quotes: `'x1elm'`

Comment: I gave you the proper answer since you came up with it first! - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put x1elm in quotes:

```
x = root.findtext('x1elm');
```

You have to pass a string that matches an XML element name. As it is, x1elm is a Python variable, and an undefined one at that.

Comment: Thank you kindly! Someone got the answer before you on the time scale.

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1">item1</item>
        <item name="item2">item2</item>
        <item name="item3">item3</item>
        <item name="item4">item4</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

**Python :**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('items.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item') 
print "Len : ", len(itemlist)
print "Attribute Name : ", itemlist[0].attributes['name'].value
print "Text : ", itemlist[0].firstChild.nodeValue
for s in itemlist :
    print "Attribute Name : ", s.attributes['name'].value
    print "Text : ", s.firstChild.nodeValue
```